# Defining values from URL

Tags: xcode, url

I am looking to define several pins in a map app I've put together, but would like to define the latitude and longitude values from a file hosted on my website, so that it can be updated continuously.

At the moment, all of these values are defined at the top of the class file, and the app works fine, but I'd like to be able to continuously update the pin locations without having to rebuild the app.

What would be the best way of pulling these definitions from a URL?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: One simple way is to just load a plist file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am very new to xcode, so sorry if this is a silly question, but if I load the plist file once, will it be accessible every time the definitions are called?

Comment: You will have to reload it. For automated updating you probably want to use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or [Push Notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it a try. The problem is that my map will eventually have about 100 pins in it... I was looking to load all of the information once in the class file, then continually reference it.